# How can one remove permanency?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The spell itself doesn't speak of a way to remove it. Dispel magic just suppresses the effect.

Are there lower spells than Mordenkainen's Disjunction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following spells are of use:

- *Dispel Magic*, Brd 3, Clr 3, Drd 4, Magic 3, Pal 3, Sor/Wiz 3 (PHB)
- *Dispelling Touch*,  Sor/Wiz 2 (PHB II)
- *Wall of Dispel Magic*, Brd 4, Clr 5, Drd 5, Sor/Wiz 5 (Und)
- *Chain Dispel*, Clr 8, Sor/Wiz 8 (PHB II)
- *Reaving Dispel* Sor/Wiz 9 (CAr)
- *Otiluke's Dispelling Screen* Sor/Wiz 4 (CAr)
- *Dispelling Breath* Sor/Wiz 4 (Dr)
- *Blackstaff* Sor/Wiz 8 (MoF)
- *Hallow/Unhallow* Clr 5, Drd 5 (PHB)
- *Disjoin* Clr 6, Sor/Wiz 6 (DCS)
- *Mordenkainen's Disjunction* Magic 9, Sor/Wiz 9 (PHB)
- *Truename Dispel* Clr 8, Drd 8, Sor/Wiz 8, Brd 6

These spells dispel most any permanent spell, but there are also lots of spells that dispel only certain kinds of spells, like *Break Enchantment*, *Quench*, and *Dispel Ward*.  Note that you need to be a higher level than the target was when the effect was made permanent for some permanent spells.  9th level spells are included for completeness.

The following magic items are also of use:

- *Magic Siphon* 25,000 gp (MIC)
- *Canaith Mandolin* 8,000 gp (MIC)

These replicate the effects of target *dispel magic*.  Other items with more restrictive effects also exist.

Answer (score 13):

The spell [Permanency](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/permanency.htm) does actually say that it can be dispelled by Dispel Magic.

> Spells cast on other creatures, objects, or locations (not on you) are vulnerable to dispel magic as normal.

There is only one caveat in this, which is when you cast Permanency on yourself, in that situation:

> This application of permanency can be dispelled only by a caster of higher level than you were when you cast the spell.

But in general, Dispel Magic will work fine assuming your level is high enough, and it'll work fine even it isn't when you're not targeting any spellcasters with it.